# passing variables to .load(html) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Say I have jquery code like this:

```
html += '<div class="index">' + item.index + '</div>';

// many more similar html += statements

// load items
$('div').append(html);
```

This html is getting too unmanageable, so I'd like to move it to an external file. What's the best way to pass variables to the HTML as i load it? Do i just have to load it and then put jquery commands in the first JS file? That's what it seems like, but I'd rather use a more template-like method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put HTML where it belongs, in the HTML file. then use a templating plugin on jQuery to expand it.

some template plugins:

- [jsRepeater](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jsrepeater)
- [jTemplates](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jTemplates)
- [noTemplate](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/noTemplate)

Comment: I have been looking for a client side replacement for the ASPx Repeater.  Looks like you nailed it.  Thanks so much.  helpful++